# Count visits by today, this week, last month and total [MySQL query]

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys this is a very simplified version of my table:
[image]

I will like to make four mysql querys to this table. All of them will have to count the total visits where **id_user** is equal to some particular *value* and **type** different from *click*. One query have to count the visits today, the other in this week, the month and the total visits. Im not very expert on MySQL, i can certainly solve this using PHP but i prefer to put the load on my sql server. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean the current week/month or within a week/month?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give these a go. I don't know what your table is called so I have referrered to it as `trafficTable`:

```
-- Visits today
select count(*) as visits_today
from trafficTable tt
where tt.type != 'click'
and tt.id_user = '19d71'
and datetime >= curdate();

-- Visits this week
select count(*) as visits_this_week
from trafficTable tt
where tt.type != 'click'
and tt.id_user = '19d71'
and yearweek(datetime) = yearweek(curdate());

-- Visits this month
select count(*) as visits_this_month
from trafficTable tt
where tt.type != 'click'
and tt.id_user = '19d71'
and year(datetime) = year(curdate())
and month(datetime) = month(curdate());

-- Total visits
select count(*) as total_visits
from trafficTable tt
where tt.type != 'click'
and tt.id_user = '19d71';

--- if you want the last month - this help other ppl in other thread
    select count(*) as visits_this_month
    from trafficTable tt
    where tt.type != 'click'
    and tt.id_user = '19d71'
    and year(datetime) <= year(curdate())
    and month(datetime) <= month(curdate());
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at this page:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

The functions `month()`, `date()`, `curdate()`, `week()` and a few others should do the trick